# Newest Shopify API not in @shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy (2021-01)

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I'm setting up an app uninstall webhook for my Shopify app. My app in Shopify Developer is set to the latest API (2021-01).

However, when I register my webhook, there's no option for ApiVersion.January21. When I set it as January21 I get the following:

```
error: invalid JSON response body at https://test-sonder.myshopify.com/admin/api/undefined/graphql.json reason: Unexpected end of JSON input.
```

This is my server.js

```
 const { ApiVersion } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy');
 const registration = await registerWebhook({
          address: `${HOST}/webhooks/apps/uninstall`,
          topic: 'APP_UNINSTALLED',
          accessToken,
          shop,
          apiVersion: ApiVersion.January21
        });
```

My package.json

```
  {
  "dependencies": {
    "@koa/router": "^10.0.0",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-react": "^1.28.0",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth": "^3.2.0",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy": "^4.1.0",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-webhooks": "^2.6.0",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^5.12.0",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "koa": "^2.13.1",
    "koa-router": "^8.0.8",
    "koa-session": "^6.1.0",
    "next": "^10.0.4",
    "ngrok": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-player": "^2.7.2",
    "store-js": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They still have to add it to the package.

You can see the SRC code here https://github.com/Shopify/quilt/blob/master/packages/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy/src/shopify-graphql-proxy.ts and you will noticed that the version is yet not present (as of writing this answer).

You can use the `unstable` version if you need something for the latest API or switch to the `October20` one if you are not looking for something that came recently to the API.

Comment: For a temporary workaround you could replace `ApiVersion.January21` with `"2021-01"`.

Answer (score 0):

[Since v6.0.0](https://github.com/Shopify/quilt/blob/main/packages/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy/CHANGELOG.md#600---2021-08-18) the enum has been updated to include new versions, but also the TypeScript type has been changed to a looser string union type to allow arbitrary versions, so that you can use any version even when the library lags behind.